# Android TV Crashing

Tags: android, android-tv

So I installed an update version 3.x of Google App (katniss aka Assistant)on my Android TV.  I can get it to run with reduced functionality as long as I don't sign into Google account.  If I do sign in I get a crash on the Google App.  Logging in ADB shows the following:

> 03-11 15:07:20.100 16604 16604 E AndroidRuntime: Process:
>   com.google.android.katniss:search, PID: 16604 03-11 15:07:20.100 16604
>   16604 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   fromHtml(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/text/Spanned; in class
>   Landroid/text/Html; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'android.text.Html' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar) 03-11
>   15:07:20.100 16604 16604 E AndroidRuntime:    at meb.a(SourceFile:79)
>   03-11 15:07:20.100 16604 16604 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   ic.onCreate(SourceFile:73) 03-11 15:07:20.100 16604 16604 E
>   AndroidRuntime:   at
>   android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2198) 03-11
>   15:07:20.100 16604 16604 E AndroidRuntime:    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
>   03-11 15:07:20.100 16604 16604 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
>   03-11 15:07:20.100 16604 16604 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 03-11
>   15:07:20.100 16604 16604 E AndroidRuntime:    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
>   03-11 15:07:20.100 16604 16604 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 03-11
>   15:07:20.100 16604 16604 E AndroidRuntime:    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 03-11 15:07:20.100
>   16604 16604 E AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 03-11 15:07:20.100
>   16604 16604 E AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 03-11 15:07:20.100 16604 16604
>   E AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 03-11
>   15:07:20.100 16604 16604 E AndroidRuntime:    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 03-11 15:07:20.100
>   16604 16604 E AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:731)
>   03-11 15:07:20.100 16604 16604 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)

That seems to suggest a framework level issue.  The Android TV is running Marshmellow 6.01 (I think) and Play Services 15.90 (also tried a few others including newer betas).

Any help would be greatly appreciated to get this sorted out.  Do I need to replace some apk's?  My first instinct is that somehow the Google App is not really compatible with Andriod 6.0 however it says it is and others have said they have it running.

I am pulling my hair out here!  Help!  (I won't be a good looking bald guy)

Answer (score 0):

I having similar issues like that before this.
What I do flash original firmware and reedit back changes you want to do.
Uninstall or reinstall is not good way to solve the problem.